# DayOfWeek (enum) in C# (concept)

Tags: c#, datetime, enums

For some time I've been working on a class that will be handling repeating tasks (for example a reminder or a scheduled thing in a calendar). I noticed that in C# the int values of enums are:
Sunday - 0
Monday - 1
...
Saturday - 6

I also see that the same is in the calendar of OS X - having the panel to choose days to schedule, it starts with Sunday at No. 1, and then it goes Monday, etc.

Why? Why a week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday? This is done so both by Microsoft (enums in C#) and Apple (order of days when selecting days).

Comment: This gets at cultural issues more than anything specifically technical.  Traditionally, in Western cultures with different forms of Judeo-Christian historical backgrounds, Saturday has been viewed as the last day of the week, because in Jewish and Christian scriptures, the Sabbath (Saturday), is seen as the day of rest and worship, the culmination of the week, with the first part of the week being for work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first day of week differs by different culture or standard the enum creator follow.

> For Christian, the first day is Sunday regards to the bible
>
> For standard ISO8601, the first day is Monday

http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/

It is configurable in Windows Region and Language

[image: In window it can be configurable]

Answer (score 1):

This Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week) does a good job explaining the cultural aspects of the 7 day week and how it varies from region to region.  This directly relates to the differences you are seeing in enums for days of the week.

> System    First day of week   Used by/in
>
> ISO-8601  Monday              EU and most of other European countries
>
> (Islamic) Saturday            Much of the Middle East
>
> (North American)  Sunday      Canada, USA, Mexico, China, Japan

[image]

Blue = Sunday

Yellow = Monday

Green = Saturday